# Eeeek! Code blocks are shown in full in IE8

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, code-block

Why are walls of code not contained within scrollable `div`s in IE8?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573623/joomla-template-whats-overriding-this-style) looks like this in IE:

[image]

Somebody **tear down this wall!**

Comment: There's a `pre { max-height: none\9; }` in the stylesheet for some reason, which seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Lol -- and the question got destroyed by a spammer! (Fixed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nobody really wanted to build that wall](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLhYIqiJlEA), but as you can see in the [SO question Jeff linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height/881597#881597), this was more or less by design – the alternative would have been to cut off most of the “wall of text”, which would have been even less desirable.

However, this IE8 bug seems to have been fixed in the meantime; I tested it, and the post gets its scrollbars correctly now. So I'm very happy to announce that we've removed the ugly `\9` hack from the CSS; after the next build, it should look as expected.

Answer (score 5):

see [IE8 overflow:auto with max-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height/881597#881597)

Actually, it looks like the fix is getting removed (the extra semicolon) through the less.css process.

Comment: So this is fixable, and the fix gets broken? (Sorry, my brain is still in the process of powering up.) Will this get fixed eventually?

Comment: Any input on this? Is this a bug, or `status-bydesign`? The behaviour still exists.