# Code that is too long to display on a single line creates a massive vertical code block

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer, code-block

If you write some code on one line which is too long for the code block to display in one, it usually, if I remember correctly, would just add a scroll bar to the bottom. Seemingly this has changed as now the code block will still display the scroll bar, but will also add a lot of extra space below. Am I right in thinking that this isn't how it should be? See below

```
//sdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

If that looks normal to people, this is what it looks like to me!

[image]

Comment: Which browser(s) do you see this on? It looks perfectly normal to me using Firefox 4, so this is probably a bug specific to your browser.

Comment: Are you using IE 8? It doesn't look this way in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: No repro with the FF5 Beta. I can't remember seeing such a thing back in FF4 or FF3.6 either.

Comment: Yes, I see the same in IE8.

Comment: Wow, the Firefox 5 beta is already out? They haven't even fixed all the minor bugs in 4 yet. I can't see how it's time for another major release.

Comment: @Cody Gray: They've switched to Chrome-Style-Versioning...there are already several complains about it, but I fear it's a marketing decision which will not change.

Comment: @Bobby Well, not *purely* marketing - the release cycle *has* been sped up, but I'd wish they'd use minor version numbers for the minor releases these new releases are

Comment: Well I was using IE8, but it was working in IE8 only a few days ago.

Comment: @anothershrubery The comments on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92515/what-happend-to-stack-overflow-on-ie8) reminded me, do you have compatibility mode turned on?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - No, IE8 browser mode and IE8 standards doc mode.

Comment: Same repro on IE8, also not in compatibility mode.

Comment: Actually just checking and it is actually the css `max-height:600px` that causes this. Has this been changed recently? Because you remove the `max-height` and it displays correctly. So I do a quick search and I find this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height This makes sense but doesn't explain how it displayed correctly a few days ago.

Comment: Repro on IE8. This started **today**. That code I posted yesterday was fine yesterday.

Comment: [This is what happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86302/eeeek-code-blocks-are-shown-in-full-in-ie8/92671#92671). So much fur IE8 not being broken anymore :\

Comment: @balpha - So it was a change on the SO side. I'd prefer the big wall of text if it was a straight choice between big wall of text for long code blocks and big code block for small pieces of code. There must be a solution that can accomodate both on IE8.

Comment: @anothershrubery: I didn't say I want to keep it this way, and I'm trying to find solutions already. Unfortunately that's not easy with an utterly broken browser.

Comment: @balpha - I didn't actually know you were the one looking after it! I'll leave it in your capable hands!

Comment: I have so far drawn *six* narwhals in that big wide open canvas.  Six.  The [supercollider freehand-circle script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-st) ***has failed me for the last time!!!***

Comment: @anothershrubery I noticed some code samples were too long but never associated it with long lines. Good job figuring that out!

Comment: Another vote for seeing this in IE8.

Comment: @Wont Get thee to a place whence ye may post a bug report.  eth.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately the eighth incarnation of a certain browser from Redmond has issues with `max-height` in conjunction with `overflow: auto` – under certain circumstances, it causes the issue you see. [Until recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86302/eeeek-code-blocks-are-shown-in-full-in-ie8/92671#92671) we had disabled `max-height` on IE8 (because of a different issue that seems since fixed).

So we can either put that hack back in, causing giant walls of text again, or not do it, and cause [Narwhal aquariums](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykwqXuMPsoc).

Or… *why not try an even uglier hack!*

After <s>some</s> testing, I found that giving the `max-height` to the element *inside* the `<pre>`, and not to the `<pre>` itself, actually works.

However, this means that a) we need a wrapper element inside the `<pre>`, and b) that wrapper needs to be `display: block` (and `overflow: visible`, but that's default).  And we're certainly not rebuilding the HTML of every post ever made to work around an IE8 bug.

Fortunately, any Markdown-created codeblock (i.e. 4-space indent) *does* have that wrapper: Codeblocks are always `<pre><code>`. So we can do something at least for those blocks (which obviously are the vast majority).

Unfortunately, this may break when someone writes their own HTML like this:

```
<pre><code>Hello</code>world</pre>
```

– but I'm making the assumption that no-one does that.

The best thing would be to apply this CSS hack only to `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`, but unfortunately IE8 doesn't support the `pre > code:only-child-not-even-any-text-node-siblings` selector, so the best we can do is `:first-child`.

This will be in the CSS after the next build:

```
.post-text pre > code:first-child
{
    max-height: 600px\9;
    display:block\9;
}
.post-text pre
{
    max-height: none\9;
}
```

This is ugly as hell, and it causes my contrived example above to break (it grows a newline), but I'm willing to give it a try, since it fixes a majority of these cases.

The weird `\9` thingadongdongs are a [browser hack](http://my.opera.com/dbloom/blog/2009/03/11/css-hack-for-ie8-standards-mode) to make these rules only count in IE8, so other browsers aren't impacted by this.

If it causes other issues again, I'm afraid we have to go back to the giant walls of text.

Comment: So the example in the question should look ok if I refresh? Because it doesn't. Or should I just see an improvement in posts created after right now?

Comment: @KateGregory: Note the "after the next build" in my post. You'll have to wait until we deploy next time; try again tomorrow.

Comment: "If it causes other issues again, I'm afraid we have to go back to the giant walls of text." -- *no*. More hacking is *always* the solution.

Comment: Post preview seems to remain not fixed.

Comment: @GSerg: Yep, forgot the preview.