# Why does a code block with a horizontal scroll bar get so tall?

Tags: support, bug, tags, edits, code-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code that is too long to display on a single line creates a massive vertical code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92768/code-that-is-too-long-to-display-on-a-single-line-creates-a-massive-vertical-code)

I just recently noticed that when a code block gets a horizontal scroll bar in IE8, it gets absurdly tall!

Here's an example from [Uncertain of how to implement a specific extension to nHibernate with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140058/uncertain-of-how-to-implement-a-specific-extension-to-nhibernate-with-linq/6141903#6141903): [screen shot with freehand circle http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/764863559.png](http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/764863559.png)

This is IE8.0.7600.16385 on Win7 x64. Enabling compatibility mode fixes the problem.